# Neo4j betweenness centrality in weighted graphs

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Let's say I have a graph, and there is one node type and one edge type in the graph. I need betweenness centralities of all nodes. I can use [neo4j algo library](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-graph-algorithms):

```
CALL algo.betweenness.stream('Node','relation', {direction:'both'})
YIELD nodeId, centrality
```

But it assumes that the cost of each edge is 1. I need a query that uses edge costs while calculating betweenness. I can't see [any way in the documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/algorithms/betweenness-centrality/).

Is there a way to calculate betweenness centrality in weighted graphs using Neo4j?

**EDIT:**

Here is an example image.

[image: betweenness example graph]

You can create this graph with this query:

```
MERGE (a0:A{name:"A0"}) MERGE (a1:A{name:"A1"}) MERGE (a2:A{name:"A2"}) MERGE (a3:A{name:"A3"}) MERGE (a4:A{name:"A4"}) MERGE (a0)-[:r{cost:2}]-(a1) MERGE (a2)-[:r{cost:1}]-(a1) MERGE (a1)-[:r{cost:3}]-(a3) MERGE (a3)-[:r{cost:1}]-(a4) MERGE (a0)-[:r{cost:6}]-(a4)
```

If I use the betweenness query given above, here are the results:

```
**nodeId    centrality**
0           1.0
1           3.5
2           0.0
3           1.0
4           0.5
```

But if we use costs given in the image, betweenness centralities should be like:

```
**nodeId    centrality**
0           0.0
1           5.0
2           0.0
3           3.0
4           0.0
```

I calculated them by hand. They can be wrong, but it gives the idea.

Comment: I think if you have only one node type, it will always show cost of each edge as one, unless you specify additional properties of the nodes

Comment: you can get the total all the weights of the relationships that you can find per node then you can sort it by total_weights in descending order.  Please give us a sample graph so that we can formulate the cypher query for you.

Comment: @krishnareddy Yes, each edge has a cost property with a float value. For example `r{cost:0.76}`

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ I added an example graph.

Comment: I couldn't find a way in Neo4j. I am using `networkx` for now. Here is the link for [betweenness.](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-2.2/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.centrality.betweenness_centrality.html#networkx-algorithms-centrality-betweenness-centrality)